# Is there a convinient way to pipe multiple kubectl commands to each other?

Tags: kubernetes, pipe, kubectl

I am looking for a way to do something like that

```
kubectl get pods -l app=foo | kubectl delete
```

I think this would be a great way to deal with multiple ressources at once, but I cannot find a reasonably easy way to do this.

Comment: need more verbs such as awk, jq to extract the pods' names.

Comment: xargs can also be useful when woring with multiline output

Answer (score 6):

You may use command substitution:

```
Kubectl delete $(kubectl get pod -l app=foo -o name)
```

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl get -o name` will write out resource names in `kind/name` format, one to a line.  You can use this in combination with tools like [**xargs**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html#tag_20_158) to run pipelines like you suggest.

```sh
kubectl get job -l app=foo -o name | xargs kubectl delete

# help we're using the long-format label names and I don't remember
# what goes after `kubectl get -l`
kubectl get job -o name | grep foo | xargs kubectl delete
```

For the very specific command you show, I've often found it easier to use [`kubectl rollout restart`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-) to trigger a Deployment's [redeployment sequence](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) without actually making any changes.  This will delete all of the pods managed by the Deployment, but only after creating new pods first; so you get the effect of restarting misbehaving Pods but without actually taking the whole application down.

```sh
kubectl rollout restart deployment/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is

```bash
kubectl get pods -l app=foo -o yaml | kubectl delete -f -
```

The first part will get all pods with the label `app: foo` and output them to stdout in yaml format. Then we pipe that output into `kubectl delete -f` where `-` is [a synonym for stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16364/513149).